# Display posts styled exactly like default posts

Tags: posts, customization

What would the parameters be for the shortcode to display a category of posts exactly like they would appear on the main blog page?

Seems pretty simple but I just don't see which parameter would do this?

thanks,

Comment: your question makes no sense.  please rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

The markup to display each regular post item is hard coded in different template files. There is now way to get it automatically – unless the theme author has used a dedicated function for this.